# Как найти все названия классов на сайте

Tags: python, классы, requests, beautiful-soup

Как найти все названия классов на сайте с помощью BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

вот

```
import requests as rq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.site.com/"
html = rq.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

class_list = [i['class'] for i in soup.find_all() if i.has_attr('class')]
print(class_list)
```

Здесь конструктор создаёт список, в котором цикл проходит по каждому элементу страницы. Если есть атрибут `class`, то просто добавляет элемент в список.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600813/is-there-a-way-to-extract-all-the-class-name-from-an-html-file-using-beautifulso